# Show that $3SAT$ is a polynomial reduction on $MSAT$, i.e. $3SAT \leq_p MSAT$

Tags: reductions, 3-sat

The exact definition of $3SAT$ and $MSAT$ are as follows:

$3SAT :=$ each clause has exactly 3 literals

$MSAT :=$ At least half of the literals of every clause are True

My intuition was, as we know that for $3SAT$ we have clauses with $3$ literals, we might just add $2$ new variables, wich are always True. This ensure, that we have at least $5$ literals per clause, of which $3$ are True, which satisfies $MSAT$.However, I am very unfamiar with this topic and I am pretty sure I am missing something. Any hints are greatly appreciated

Comment: Intuition is not proof. I suggest looking at several NP-hardness proofs to see what an NP-hardness proof looks like.

Comment: I never said it would be

Comment: The hint is to try proving the result formally. This is how we know if our intuition works.

Comment: The "exact definitions" of 3SAT and 3MSAT are not so exact. For example it is unclear if, in the 3MSAT problem, you are requiring at least half of the literals to be satisfied for a clause to be satisfied, or you are just saying that any clause of the input instance has at least half of the literals that correspond to asserted variables. Moreover it is not clear why there is a 3 in the name of 3MSAT. Are clauses required to have at most 3 variables? Are they required to have exactly 3 variables?